# XML publisher Oracle Apps - I added a query to the data model of a RDF file

Tags: xml, publisher

I added a query to the data model of a RDF file,made some changes to the rtf template accordingly but thats causing no data to display.

Earlier it was working fine.

Can you guys help.

Comment: in order for folks to help you, please include a code sample and explain the difference between your working version and the non-working version, then explicitly indicate what stopped working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.